# Cloud Text Recognition or On-Device? Google Text-Recognition Services

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ocr, text-recognition

I am considering using Google's API for Text Recognition - what is the difference between the On-Device option and the Cloud option that is part of firebase?  Both in the implementation and the result -  how do I know which one is best for my particular app?

A little bit of background:

- I am building a Xamarin.Forms cross-platform app
- I am a complete beginner (but have worked with Firebase Realtime Database and Auth)

Can these OCR options be integrated with cross-platform Xamarin.Forms?  Or only with native apps?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the difference between the On-Device option and the Cloud option that is part of firebase?

**On-device text recognition** is part of the new standalone ML Kit SDK, which you can use with or without Firebase.

**Cloud text recognition** is part of Firebase ML, which includes all of Firebase's cloud-based ML features.

[image]

More detailed info, please take a look:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/recognize-text

You can choose one way to do according to your  requirement.